# Replace only last number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div with Class name "**separator**" which holds a URL with different paths, but there is one similarity in each URL. what i did is get the URL from that div and replace a specific parameter.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="separator">
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/images/s1600/photo.jpg"><img src="http://www.mydomain.com/images/s1600/photo.jpg" height="225" width="400" /></a>
</div>
```

**Here is the JavaScript Code:**

```
var ImageSource = document.getElementsByClassName('separator')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
ImageSource = ImageSource.replace("0", "0-d");
```

This code works fine, i only want to target the last `0` from `/s1600/` because when this value has 2 Zeros it outputs like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/images/s160-d0/photo.jpg
```

**Which should be**

```
http://www.mydomain.com/images/s1600-d/photo.jpg
```

Please suggest some solution... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `0` followed by a slash.

```
ImageSource = ImageSource.replace(/0\//, '0-d/')
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want a regular expression:

```
ImageSource = ImageSource.replace(/0(\D*)$/, "0-d$1");
```

That says "match a 0 followed by a series of non-digit characters through to the end of the string, capturing the non-digit characters, and replace them with `0-d` followed by the non-digits".

Details:

- The `0` is literal (match a `0`).
- The `(` and `)` define a *capture group*.
- The `\D` means "a non-digit" (so, *not* 0-9).
- The `*` means "zero or more of the previous thing" (in this case, non-digits).
- The `$` means "end of string"

In the replacement string, `$1` refers to the text within the capture group.

Comment: Not working for me... The Request URL has this value `/s1600/` which needs to be changed into this `/s1600-d/`. This value can be changed into /s1920/, /s800/, i only want to change the LAST `0` to `0-d`. the Regex you provided didn't worked :(

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder for explaining nicely and clearly :) My problem is solved now

Comment: @XeBii: *"the Regex you provided didn't worked"* Yes, it does: http://jsbin.com/icavap/1